# Can the Dispatcher spend actions to allow others to knowledge transfer?

Tags: pandemic

I saw the following question: [exchanging cards in pandemic](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/2754/exchanging-cards-in-pandemic)

And now I am wondering if the following (specifically step 3) is a legal move in pandemic?
1. Play the dispatcher (can spend actions to move other pawns).
2. Use a couple of my actions to move other player's pawns into the same city.
3. **Spend an action to allow them to exchange cards.**

The linked question has this excerpt from the rules:

> Transfer a card from one player to another. Every card transferred
>   costs 1 action. Both your pawn and your fellow player’s pawn must be
>   in the same city, and you may only transfer the card of the city that
>   you are in together.

The first sentence says that any players can be involved in the transfer, but the second makes it sound like the active player needs to be involved.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No. This is not a legal action.**

The Dispatcher's two abilities are:

> - Move your fellow players' pawns on your turn as if they were your own
> - Move any pawn to another city containing a pawn for 1 action

The rule book has a very specific wording for each action. The actions Drive (or Ferry), Direct Flight, Charter Flight, and Shuttle Flight all use the word "move" to explain what you do during that action. All of the others, including Share Knowledge, do not. These actions do not deal with moving, which is all the Dispatcher is allowed to do to other pawns.

Or more simplistically, the [rules](http://www.zmangames.com/boardgames/files/pandemic/Pandemic_Rules.pdf) state specifically:

> The **Dispatcher** may move other player’s pawns on his turn (using any of the available **Basic** actions) as if they were his own pawn. He may also spend an action to move a pawn to any city that contains another pawn. He may only move other players’ pawns if they permit him to do so. Note: For the **Charter Flight** action, the Dispatcher must play the card corresponding to the current location of the pawn he wishes to move.

The Basic actions only include the four I mentioned above, plus Pass. You cannot spend an action to allow other players to trade cards using the Dispatcher; Share Knowledge is a Special action and outside of the Dispatcher's abilities.

Comment: Just remember you can do what he suggested when moving the Researcher - as the Researcher's special ability is to trade cards outside of their turn as well.

Comment: @AviadBenDov No where can I find that the Researcher can trade cards outside of their turn. Since Share Knowledge uses an action, it can only be done during any player's turn.

Comment: @AviadBenDov The only way this works is if the Dispatcher moves the Researcher to the city they are in with the intention of the Researcher giving the Dispatcher a card. However, this is true for any pawn. The Researcher is the only one that could give the Dispatcher any card; any other player is restricted to trading cards of the city both players are in.

Comment: what you say is true of course, except that the Researcher can hand over cards out of turn. It says so in a comment under the Share Knowledge explanation in the rules.