# Pandemic Legacy Researcher relationship (Feb spoliers)

Tags: pandemic-legacy-season-1

I am not sure if this is asked before but I don't want to search too much as keep coming across spoilers.

My question is, if you have a coworker relationship with a researcher, I know the researcher can then pass any card at any time to her coworker, but can the coworker also pass **any** card to the researcher, or does it only work one way?

I'm not sure we've got the understanding of researchers and passing cards correct and don't want to carry on the game if we're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way only.

**Reason:**

Researcher ability works one way only (He can only GIVE card with his ability, NOT TAKE.)
Co-worker relationship make good combo with researcher, but don't extend his ability to the "taking" part. (Although, it is possible for other players, to take cards form researcher, in their turns. So also his co-worker can take advantage of this.)

Answer (score 2):

**The Researcher may pass any card, but they can only receive a card as per normal Share Knowledge rules.**

This is actually explicit on the Researcher card (emphasis mine):

> You may **give** any 1 of your City cards when you Share Knowledge. It need not match your city. A player who Shares Knowledge with you on their can **take** any 1 of your City cards.

The card itself only specifies that the Researcher can pass any card. It does not specify that they can receive any card. The accepted answer on [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/2754/exchanging-cards-in-pandemic) has the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

While the ability to pass ANY card only applies to cards coming from the Researcher, the co-worker of the Researcher still gets the normal co-worker ability to pass the card of the city the Researcher is in, without needing to be in that city themselves.